# Positioning div left/right or top/bottom of a mouse click with CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I need a popup to open from a mouse click's position. From a usability view, when the click's happen near the edges of window, I'm adjusting the position[to the right/ left of click & top/bottom of the click] of popup in JS as below:

```
function myfunc(e) {
let ele = document.getElementById('my-dialog');
ele.style["left"] =
  (window.innerWidth - e.pageX) < ele.offsetWidth ? e.pageX - ele.offsetWidth : e.pageX;
ele.style["top"] =
  (window.innerHeight - e.pageY) < ele.offsetHeight ? e.pageY - ele.offsetHeight : e.pageY; }
```

Is there a way this can be achieved using just CSS(or is there a better JS solution to the problem.)

Minimal working code example [here](https://gist.github.com/knomdlo/28f420106a9b273749e126c34486cbef).

Comment: You can have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492910/open-popup-at-clicked-position

Answer (score 0):

See a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/drumperl/ce532rnf/

To get this working, I changed the `left` and `top` style settings to add 'px'. According to the spec, a length setting requires a relative or absolute unit of measurement like 'px', '%' or 'em'.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

```
function myfunc(e) {
    let ele = document.getElementById('my-dialog');

    var newLeft = (window.innerWidth - e.pageX) < ele.offsetWidth ? e.pageX - ele.offsetWidth : e.pageX;
    ele.style.left = newLeft + 'px';

    var newTop = (window.innerHeight - e.pageY) < ele.offsetHeight ? e.pageY - ele.offsetHeight : e.pageY;
    ele.style.top = newTop + 'px';
  }
  document.onclick = myfunc;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the mention about adding unit, but I'm checking if there's a CSS trick that can do the same for me to avoid javascript entirely.